# Using sent_tokenize in a specific area of a file in Python using NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, nltk

I have a file with thousands of sentences, and I want to find the sentence containing a specific character/word.

Originally, I was tokenizing the entire file (using `sent_tokenize`) and then iterating through the sentences to find the word. However, this is too slow. Since I can quickly find the indices of the words, can I use this to my advantage? Is there a way to just tokenize an area around a word (i.e. figure out which sentence contains a word)?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm in Python and using the NLTK library.

Answer (score 2):

What platform are you using? On unix/linux/macOS/cygwin, you can do the following:

```
sed 's/[\.\?\!]/\n/' < myfile | grep 'myword'
```

Which will display just the lines containing your word (and the sed will get a very rough tokenisation into sentences). If you want a solution in a particular language, you should say what you're using!

EDIT for Python:

The following will work---it only calls the tokenization if there's a regexp match on your word (this is a very fast operation). This will mean you only tokenize lines that contain the word you want:

```
import re
import os.path

myword = 'using'
fname = os.path.abspath('path/to/my/file')

try:
    f = open(fname)

    matching_lines = list(l for l in f if re.search(r'\b'+myword+r'\b', l))
    for match in matching_lines:
        #do something with matching lines
        sents = sent_tokenize(match)
except IOError:
    print "Can't open file "+fname
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Oops, I'm using python and the nltk library.

Comment: I'll add in a Python version then

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I don't have line breaks between sentences. My problem is that I have on big blob of text, and I don't know where the boundaries are (and thus how far around the word I need to tokenize.)

Comment: There are no paragraphs either? If you genuinely just have a lump of sentences, you can do a coarse segmentation by doing a re.sub(r'[\.\?!]',r'\n', str). This will just split on fullstop, question mark or exclamation mark. To guard against it all going wrong with this, you could apply the full tokenisation to a window of "sentences" around the critical match

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that might speed up the search. You create an additional list in which you store the **running total** of the word counts for each sentence in your big text. Using a generator function that I learned from Alex Martelli, try something like:

```
def running_sum(a):
  tot = 0
  for item in a:
    tot += item
    yield tot

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

sen_list = sent_tokenize(bigtext)
wc = [len(s.split()) for s in sen_list]
runningwc = list(running_sum(wc)) #list of the word count for each sentence (running total for the whole text)

word_index = #some number that you get from word index

for index,w in enumerate(runningwc):
    if w > word_index:
        sentnumber = index-1 #found the index of the sentence that contains the word
        break

print sen_list[sentnumber]
```

Hope the idea helps.

**UPDATE**: If sent_tokenize is what is slow, then you can try avoiding it altogether. Use the known index to find the word in your big text.

Now, move forward and backward, character by character, to detect sentence end and sentence starts. Something like a "[.!?] " (a period, exclamation or a question mark, followed by a space) would signify and sentence start and end. You will only be searching in the vicinity of your target word, so it should be much faster than sent_tokenize.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll have to take a closer look tomorrow, but I think the slowest part for me is actually the `sen_list = sent_tokenize(bigtext)`. (The tokenizer, that is.) Surprisingly, iterating through the sentences isn't too bad, although I like your idea.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping sent_tokenize could search in the vicinity of a word (working outwards from there.) I really need sent_tokenize because it's smart enough to ignore periods in abbreviations with its NLP and all.